# ffmpeg can't find a window title of which contains accented characters

Tags: windows, ffmpeg

Windows10 64 bit operating system.
When I'm using the following command

```
ffmpeg.exe -f gdigrab -framerate 16 -i title="Bassano_Virtus_55_ST_vs_FC_Südtirol" -b:v 768k  -s "1024x768" -loglevel verbose test.flv
```

i'm getting this error:

```
[gdigrab @ 0000000002677600] Can't find window 'Bassano_Virtus_55_ST_vs_FC_S├╝dtirol', aborting.
title=Bassano_Virtus_55_ST_vs_FC_S├╝dtirol: Input/output error
```

At the same time, when I'm using this command without accented characters, everything is working.
Thank you.

Comment: Try changing the code page for your `cmd` shell.

Comment: chcp 65001 does not help, though the error message is displayed correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to old discussions I found on the ffmpeg site,
it does not support unicode. If it is indeed an ANSI application,
this might explain why it cannot handle accented characters.

I think your best option, if you don't want to become an ffmpeg developer,
is to change the title of the window before starting ffmpeg.

Here are some free products I have found but never used :

- [Captain](http://www.dcmembers.com/skrommel/download/captain/) by Skrommel
- [Window Title Changer](http://windowtitlechanger.blogspot.fr/2013/04/change-any-window-title-in-runtime.html)
- [Window Title Changer](https://www.murgee.com/window-title-changer/)
  (another one)

You might need to run them as Administrator.